# Microsoft Graph Api token invalid or not authorized?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to read the user's data from Azure Active Directory via Microsofts' Graph API. Using the Graph Explorer I'm able to get all users but using a stand alone application I end up with an "unauthorized" response after receiving a token. I'm clearly missing some steps but it isn't obvious to me what steps that would be. Any insight would be appreciated

The code below is based off a MSFT sample:

```
// config values
// authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ TENANT ID }/oauth2/" 
// resource uri = "https:// APP NAME .azurewebsites.net";
// graph uri = https://graph.windows.net/TENANT ID/ also tried https://graph.windows.net/v1.0/


// short form
public async void GetUsers( ADConfiguration config )   
{
     _authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config.GetAuthority());
     _clientCredential = new ClientCredential(config.ClientId, config.ClientSecret);

     AuthenticationResult result = null;

     // obtain the token, this part is still successful
     result = await _authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(config.ResourceUri, _clientCredential );

    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);


     string address = config.GetGraphiUri() + "users?api-version=1.6";

     // this response is always unauthorized
     HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(address);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answer your new problem . From you code , you are acquiring token using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service). In the client credentials flow, permissions are granted directly to the application itself.

Since you are using Azure AD Graph API , you need to add `application permission` :

1. In the Azure portal, choose your application, click on `Settings`
2. In the Settings menu, choose the `Required permissions` section ,select `Windows Azure Active Directory`(Azure ad graph api) , add related application permissions your app requires .
3. Inside your app's blade, hit `Grant Permissions` to do admin consent with your admin's credential .

Comment: Thanks, like I was telling Juunas we have two APIs that have access: 'Windows Azure Active Directory' and 'Microsoft Graph', both have permissions to do everything. 

I suspect I'm overlooking something basic here ...

Comment: Please decode your access token using [this tool](http://jwt.calebb.net/) , and check whether any application permission included in `roles` claim

Comment: The token decoder site that Nan pointed you to may disappear in the future.  Please use this one instead (which is functionally equivalent): https://jwtinspect.azurewebsites.net/.  @Mark which API is it you are using AAD or Microsoft Graph? In either case, if you are using client_credentials flow, an admin will need to grant consent/permissions for your API calls to work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Dan. I've tried both variations based on the feedback provided by Juunas. None of them worked for us, so I agree we are not given the right permissions. 

We can make changes to the app registration permissions but the 'grant consent' step gets denied. I opened a ticket with the admin to provide access. Regrettably, these request take quite a bit of time to process in our organization. I will report back once I know more.

Comment: Admin gave us the correct access. The application works now as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your config values seem off:

**Authority** should be: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT ID}`.

It seems to me that you are trying to use Azure AD Graph API, not Microsoft Graph API.

In that case:

**Resource URI** should be: `https://graph.windows.net/`. (MS Graph API is `https://graph.microsoft.com/`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The suggestions changed the error message from 'unauthorized' to 'forbidden'.  A lateral move I guess...

I believe the resource uri refers to an AD server on Azure. Either way I've tried either variation without much success.

Comment: Forbidden means your app does not have the necessary permissions. Check that you have added them for Azure AD Graph.

Comment: We have two APIs that have access: 'Windows Azure Active Directory' and 'Microsoft Graph', both have permissions to do everything. I've looked for 'Azure AD Graph' to add for API Access but that doesn't come up as an option.

Comment: Have you also *granted* the permissions? There is a button for that.

Comment: I'm not authorized to do so, I've asked the admin and I assume he did. I'll verify that is indeed the case.